# How to replace text in <label> using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<label>
  Auto zoom 
  <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="autoZoom" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;">
  <span class="switchery switchery-small" style="box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s;">
    <small style="left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;"></small>
  </span>
</label>
```

I have this code above, I want to replace "Auto zoom" to "Test", how do I do that?

```
$("#div label:contains('Auto zoom')").text("Test");
```

I tried using the code above, which is obviously not working, it will remove the input type checkbox behind too...

Comment: Your code works if your remove `#div`, since you haven't added this to your HTML, then we can't know if it's supposed to be there or not.

Comment: Why you have the `input` directly in `label` ?

Comment: `<label>Auto zoom</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="autoZoom" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;"><span class="switchery switchery-small" style="box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s;"><small style="left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;"></small></span>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman because that's what you're supposed to do with checkboxes...? The `label` wrapping the checkbox expands its hit area

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan BUT, label already expand hit area because when you click on label it the same thing like you click on checkbox... no ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but hopefully this makes it clearer to you: https://jsfiddle.net/0y5k5yLk/

Comment: Remove # and  Div

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman only if you use `<label for=` otherwise you nest the checkbox in the label

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes but it's logique to add the `for` attribute on a label.. It's the good practice to separate input of label..

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman I wouldn't say either is a 'best practice'. They both have perfectly valid use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to wrap the text in another element, like a `span`, then change the `text()`.

Assuming you cannot change the HTML, then you can do what you require by using `contents()` and retrieving the first textNode, like this:

```js
var label = $('label').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim();
})[0];

label.nodeValue = label.nodeValue.replace('Auto zoom', 'Test');
```

```css
.switchery-small {
  box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset;
  border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s;
}

.switchery-small small {
  left: 0px;
  transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  Auto zoom Foo Bar
  <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="autoZoom" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;">
  <span class="switchery switchery-small">
    <small></small>
  </span>
</label>
```

Also note that I moved the inline `style` attribute out to rules in an external stylesheet. This is much better as it de-clutters the HTML and separate the HTML from the styling.

Comment: Can I only replace the specific text "Auto Zoom" to "Test"? Since there are tons of label in that html.

Comment: Yep, you can use `replace()` to target only the words you want to change. I updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend wrapping your text around `span` tag.

```js
$(".labelTitle").text("Test");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
<span class="labelTitle">Auto zoom </span>
<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="autoZoom" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;">
<span class="switchery switchery-small" style="box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s;">
<small style="left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;"></small>
</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I'm not the one coded these, I'm using jquery to edit a web game.. <div class="options-box zoomGroup"><h5 class="menu-main-color">Zoom</h5><label>Auto zoom <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="autoZoom" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;"><span class="switchery switchery-small" style="box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s;"><small style="left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;"></small></span></label></div>
How should i add span?

Answer (score 0):

Try Code:
Just Remove # and Div

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label>Auto zoom <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="autoZoom" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;"><span class="switchery switchery-small" style="box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s;"><small style="left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;"></small></span></label>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("label:contains('Auto zoom')").text("Test");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Like all the other answers before it, and the question itself, this also removes the inputs.

Answer (score -2):

You have to select the  with:

```
$("label:contains('Auto zoom')").text('Test');
```

With your jquery:

> $('#div')...

You are selecting a `element` with `id='div'`. If you can put a id or class in the label element, is too much easy, like:

`<label id='label_test'> Auto zoom...</label>`

Then you can do like:

```
$('#label_test').text("Test");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The question is about selecting just the text without also removing any nested controls.